# some trouble for my jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have some trouble in this code, I want to make a judge if the `next().children()` div hasn't lengh, then do an ajax require. But it always make an ajax require even the div has content.

Here is the html code:

```
<noscript>
<style>
.more{display:none;}
</style>
</noscript>
<!-- main content -->
<p class="click hidden" rel="12345">View more</p>
<div class="more">
    <h5>Relative post</h5>
    <div class="relative-post"></div>
    <!-- comment area -->
</div>
<!-- main content -->
<p class="click hidden" rel="23456">View more</p>
<div class="more">
    <h5>Relative post</h5>
    <div class="relative-post"></div>
    <!-- comment area -->
</div>
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click").live('click',function() {
        if($(this).next('.more').is(':visible')){
            $(this).next('.more').css('display','none');
        }else{
            $(this).next('.more').css('display','block');
        }
        if($(this).next('.more').children('.relative-post:has(*)').length){
            }else{
            var $this = $(this);
            var item_id = $this.attr('rel');
            $.ajax({
                url: "process",
                dataType: "html",
                type: 'POST', 
                data: 'post=' + item_id, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){ 
                    $this.next('.more').children('.relative-post').html(data);
                }
            }); 
                    }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can clean up your show/hide code by using jQuery toggle()... http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Btw live() method is deprecated. Use on().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code

```
if($(this).next('.more').children('.relative-post:has(*)').length)
```

with following

```
 if($(this).next('.more').children('.relative-post').html())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.click', function() {
        var next = $(this).next('.more');
        next.toggle(!next.is(':visible'));

        if (next.children('.relative-post:empty').length) {
            var item_id = $(this).attr('rel');
            $.ajax({
                url: "process",
                dataType: "html",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {post: item_id},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    next.children('.relative-post').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M5hfH/3/)

Comment: Instead of `children` you may want to use `contents`. I up-voted though.

Comment: `contents` will get textnodes as well, but I don't see how I would use it here, as the `:empty` expression is what checks the element to see if it's empty, and that includes textnodes as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`if($(this).next('.more').children('.relative-post').html().length){`